# Apache won't start in MAMP Pro

Tags: mamp

I’ve tried several ways to get MAMP PRO to work for me. The main issue is that Apache keeps conking out, not sure why.

Apache starts when i don’t have any servers other than local. But when i start to create new servers Apache won’t run.

Here is my setup per screen shots:

shot 1: http://kualitydesign.com/css-tricks/mamp-1.png

shot 2: http://kualitydesign.com/css-tricks/mamp-2.png

I’ve googled, but all i’ve been able to find is how to start a new server, which i know how to do when MP starts normally.

What i don’t know how to do is troubleshoot MP when it Apache doesn’t start. Really need to work locally for a new WP build and would love to get this up and running.

If anyone has had this same issue, can spot my error, or has other ways to fix the issue and cares to share, that would rule!

My hunch, and it’s a very noob hunch, is that Apache on MAC is running and it’s conflicting with MP’s apache, if that’s even possible. I just re-call reading that somewhere.

Thank you.

Comment: here are 2 other screen shots

Comment: Please check the mamp after restarting the computer, it might help u out

Comment: Here are 2 other screen shots shot 3: http://kualitydesign.com/css-tricks/mamp-3.png

shot 4: http://kualitydesign.com/css-tricks/mamp-4.png

Comment: Thanks @FayeqAliKhan i tried that and it still doesn't work i'm worried that learning iterm and possibly some sudo command that i may have entered at some point is preventing it from working. I sometimes blindly install stuff to learn it but break something else in the process. Any other suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: Figured it out, i just did a complete uninstall and re-installed and worked great.

Comment: Great its working for you now :)